# How is the JavaScript API, currentTime implemented?

Tags: javascript, html

While seeking thru media in a HTML5 player, you can jump (seek) to a specific time by using the currentTime construct.

How is the JavaScript API, currentTime implemented in the browser?

For example,

```
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds in the video
```

What I see on the wire (with wireshark) is:

```
GET /videos/q1fx20VZ-52qL9xLP.mp4 HTTP/1.1
...
Range: bytes=47864170-
```

So, my guess is, some entity on the client side is doing the conversion from **time domain to byte domain**.

Please help demystify this?

Comment: Remember that _mp4_ is a container. I'd assume that as a container, it has some kind of index for timecodes. So the browser is using it's knowledge of _mp4_ to request the correct part of the file for the time you're asking of it. This is like asking how does a media player know which byte to seek to when you choose a time to play from.

Comment: For playing video, there is a _little bit_ more involved then just JavaScript …

Comment: @Paul S. - I think you are definitely guiding me in the right direction. Yes, the mp4 container carries some kind of index (at the beginning of the file). If I delve into that syntax, it may be holding the time-to-byte conversion so that the browser can make a simple byte-range request.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-currenttime,

> The `currentTime` attribute must, on getting, return the [media element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#media-element)'s
>   [default playback start position](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#default-playback-start-position), unless that is zero, in which case it
>   must return the element's [official playback position](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#official-playback-position). The returned
>   value must be expressed in seconds. On setting, if the [media element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#media-element)
>   has a [current media controller](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#current-media-controller), then the user agent must throw an
>   [`InvalidStateError`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#invalidstateerror) exception; otherwise, if the [media element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#media-element)'s
>   [`readyState`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-readystate) is [`HAVE_NOTHING`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-have_nothing), then it must set the [media element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#media-element)'s
>   [default playback start position](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#default-playback-start-position) to the new value; otherwise, it must
>   set the [official playback position](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#official-playback-position) to the new value and then [seek](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-seek) to
>   the new value. The new value must be interpreted as being in seconds.

It seems you want the `seek` case.

Then, according to http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-seek,

> The `seekable` attribute must
>   return a new   static normalized
>   `TimeRanges` object that represents the ranges of the  
>   media resource, if any, that the user
>   agent is able to seek to, at the time the   attribute is
>   evaluated.
>
> If the user agent can seek to anywhere in the media resource, e.g.   because it is a
>   simple movie file and the user agent and the server support HTTP Range
>   requests,   then the attribute would return an object with one range,
>   whose start is the time of the first   frame (the earliest possible position,
>   typically zero), and whose end is the same as   the time of the first
>   frame plus the duration attribute's   value
>   (which would equal the time of the last frame, and might be positive
>   Infinity).
>
> The range might be continuously changing, e.g. if
>   the user agent is buffering a   sliding window on an infinite stream.
>   This is the behavior seen with DVRs viewing live TV, for
>   instance.
>
> Media
>   resources might be internally scripted or   interactive. Thus, a
>   media element could play in a non-linear
>   fashion. If this   happens, the user agent must act as if the
>   algorithm for seeking was used whenever the current playback position
>   changes in a discontinuous fashion (so that the relevant events fire).
>   If the media   element has a current media controller, then
>   the user agent must seek   the
>   media controller appropriately instead.

Answer (score 1):

Most people think about video files like `.mp4` as a files, but in fact `avi, mp4, mkv` and [many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) are just containers that store a lot of information inside of them. The best analogy is an archive (you look at is as one file, but it is many files just grouped together and compressed). Most of the time this container has audio and video inside of it (which are synchronized) and some metadata which helps the program which reads this container to understand what is inside. You can read about codecs and containers [here](http://www.techhive.com/article/213612/all_about_video_codecs_and_containers.html)

When you are watching a video you in fact are accessing both of this streams (video and audio). During this time your computer is doing multiple things:

- decoding video stream and shows them as a series of images (like animated gifs)
- decoding audio and forces your speakers to sound it
- some additional things

In order to know how the navigation through the video (and basically decoding) is working you need to understand how the video is coded. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types). Basically everything is evolving around three main frames:

1. I‑frames are the least compressible but don't require other video frames to decode.
2. P‑frames can use data from previous frames to decompress and are more compressible than I‑frames.
3. B‑frames can use both previous and forward frames for data reference to get the highest amount of data compression.

This is done because if you will store a video as a series of .jpg pictures it would be really huge. P-frames and B-frames allows you to save space. (If you once tried to open not fully downloaded video from torrent, and saw that when you are forwarding back and force you can barely see what is inside, right now you know why this happened, P-frames and B-frames do not store all information). So when you are moving forward and backward you are navigating between I-frames. Container stores information about position of these I-frames and allows you to quickly navigate through the file. HTML5 provide you with and API through JS to access this data and when you make your API call `mediaElement.currentTime = 122` the browser is just converting the time to a offset from which you have to read new information. If you want, you can dive in some opensource browser code and check how exactly is this implemented.

Was written during the end of the day so I want to eat and do not have enough time. If you see some inaccuracies - feel free to edit.

Comment: How does the browser know to generate a decoder-friendly offset? Any offset wouldn't do. I thoughts the "Movie Fragment Random Access" or **mfra** in Mp4 container was the answer. However, I see streams without it that work. Yes, diving into the browser code would be good.